# I am shaped like a ring and made out of metal - what am I?

Tags: riddle, word

I am shaped like a ring and made out of metal,

I can be a burden,

but then also be very comforting,

My neighbors are the ones with bones and muscle,

You use me for leisure and sometimes for showing off,

And it doesn't matter for me because all I am, is just a piece of metal,

***So what am I?***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the answer is simply

> a ring.

Seems a bit weird given the first line, but it's the only thing I can make fit the rest.

*I am shaped like a ring and made out of metal,*

> Well, obviously!

*I can be a burden,*

> Lord of the Rings reference (thanks **d'alar'cop** for catching this one)

*but then also be very comforting,*

> Could be another LotR reference (the Ring being like a drug, and possessing it gives some kind of comfort) or to marriage.

*My neighbors are the ones with bones and muscle,*

> A ring is snuggled up next to the bones and muscles of fingers.

*You use me for leisure and sometimes for showing off,*

> Leisure could be a reference to the five-ring symbol of the Olympics. Rings are definitely used to show off or display wealth.

*And it doesn't matter for me because all I am, is just a piece of metal,*

> Again, obviously!

Comment: "burdensome" could refer to a painful marriage or to LOTR

Comment: God is the master of trolls - I knew it

Comment: How do you explain "You use me for leisure"?

Comment: People wear jewellery (including rings) to attend social gatherings (leisure activities).

Comment: @d'alar'cop No, there's only [one](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10466/the-traveler-and-the-blood-thirsty-troll) master of trolls now! Thanks for the LotR idea - I've edited it in.

Comment: @CyanogenCX I've edited in an explanation for this. Ian's idea could also work.

Comment: There's no muscles in your fingers. ;)

Comment: If the answer is really "Ring", you shouldn't add this line "_I'm shaped like a ring_"  . . . It doesn't feel good.

Comment: @Nai I know, but tell that to God!

Comment: No, I will just tell you. @randal'thor I just want to make it better way if you can. Why you gotta say like that? If it was God, I don't even have to tell.

Comment: @Nai The OP's username is God. I didn't write this riddle! Sorry for the confusion - again, blame God ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor Okay. I got it. & I saw you on many puzzling pages, well, understood. I meant to comment under God! :( :)